# Find missing rows between 2 variables in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using PHP to access a SQL server database and I have 2 numbers stored as PHP variables.

For example one variable is `10` and the other variable is `15`.

I need to output a list of 'missing' documents i.e rows where a certain column `col1` does not contain numbers between `10` and `15`.

Example:

```
col1
----
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Variables:

```
$start = 10
$end = 15
```

Desired result using SQL only:

```
result
------
11
13
15
```

Comment: Why did you tag `PHP` since you want a solution using only `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a numbers/tally table, you can use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a `LEFT JOIN`

**Example**

```
Declare @R1 int = 10
Declare @R2 int = 15

Select Result= N
 From (
       Select Top (@R2-@R1+1) 
              N=@R1-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)) 
        From master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
       ) A
 Left Join YourTable B  on A.N = B.[col1]
 Where B.[col1] is null
```

**Returns**

```
Result
11
13
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in different ways, one approach is to generate a tally table and do left join as below:

```
Declare @start int = 10
Declare @end int = 15

;With CTE_Numbers as (
    Select top (@end - @start+1) RowN = @start + Row_number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)) -1
        from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
        ) 
        Select c.RowN as Result from CTE_Numbers c 
            left join yourtable t
            on c.RowN = t.col1
            where t.col1 is null
```

Comment: Yes just noticed, if 10 is not there it will be missed... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare  @t table (col1 int);
    insert into @t values
    (2),
    (4),
    (6),
    (8),
    (10),
    (12),
    (14),
    (16),
    (18),
    (20)

    declare @start int = 10,
            @end int = 15;

    with nums as
    (
    select n
    from
        (
        select row_number() over(order by getdate()) n
        from sys.all_columns c1 cross join sys.all_columns c2
        ) t
    where n between @start and @end
    )

    select *
    from nums
    where not exists (select col1 from @t t where nums.n = t.col1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`dbo.Numbers(Numbers PK)` table](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) ([reference #2](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)) and following query:

```
DECLARE @start INT = 10, @end INT = 15

SELECT x.Col1
FROM dbo.SourceTable x
WHERE x.Col1 >= @start AND x.Col1 <= @end
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Numbers n
    WHERE n.Number >= @start AND n.Number <= @end
    AND n.Number = x.Col1
)
```